# How can I move a window that's unselectable behind a dialog?

Tags: windows, winapi, dialog

I have an application (executable) where it displays an update dialog upon launch in front of the parent window.  The dialog, of course, maintains the focus and top of the Z order for the application.

The parent window is therefore unselectable and cannot be moved or dragged etc.

Is there a way to modify the position of windows without focus in an external application?

Comment: [SetWindowPos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos).

Comment: How would I get the window handle in the first place for another application?

Comment: By [looking for it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumwindows). You'll have to have a plan how to identify it.

Comment: Thanks, I will go ahead and attempt that and report.

Comment: Or, if you know the exact class name and/or window title, [`FindWindow()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-findwindoww) instead of `EnumWindows()`

Comment: If it's the parent window of your dialog then you already know its handle since you used it when creating the dialog.

Comment: *"The dialog ... maintains the focus and top of the Z order ... The parent window is therefore unselectable"* - That's not why the owner cannot be interacted with. A **modal** dialog is modal, because it disables its owner. You disable a window by calling [EnableWIndow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enablewindow).